# FILTER DAX function is missing the rows in cases where sales for previous DAY is not available

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to show the previous day sale along with the current sale. The problem is that the day which does not have previous day sale, that row is getting skipped. I am using the below DAX function :

```
SumInRange = 
var sel = selectedvalue('Table'[Date])
return
CALCULATE(SUMX(DISTINCT('Table'[Date]),CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Sale]))),FILTER(all('Table'),'Table'[Date] = sel -1))
```

To replicate the scenario first step is to create **Dim Date** table using - >

```
Dim Date = GENERATESERIES(date(2019,01,01),date(2019,12,31),1)
```

second Step is to create DataTable ->

```
Table = DATATABLE("Date",DATETIME,"Flag1",STRING,"Flag2",STRING,"Sale",INTEGER,{
{"8/1/2019","True","True",200},
{"8/2/2019","False","True",80},
{"8/2/2019","False","True",80},
{"8/2/2019","False","True",80},
{"8/2/2019","False","True",80},
{"8/2/2019","False","True",80},
{"9/3/2019","False","True",60},
{"9/4/2019","False","True",10},
{"9/5/2019","False","True",100},
{"9/6/2019","False","True",30},
{"9/7/2019","False","True",60},
{"9/8/2019","False","False",150},
{"9/9/2019","False","False",80},
{"9/10/2019","False","False",90},
{"9/11/2019","False","False",30},
{"9/12/2019","False","False",20},
{"10/13/2019","False","True",50},
{"10/14/2019","False","True",60},
{"10/15/2019",BLANK(),BLANK(),BLANK()},
{"10/16/2019",BLANK(),BLANK(),BLANK()}
})
```

3rd Step - create a relation between these tables on date column

4th step - create Measure using -

```
SumInRange = 
var sel = selectedvalue('Table'[Date])
return
CALCULATE(SUMX(DISTINCT('Table'[Date]),CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Sale]))),FILTER(all('Table'),'Table'[Date] = sel -1))
```

Output of this is attached as the screenshot. You will observe that the date that does not have previous day sale is getting omitted like - 08/01/2019. Row for this date is getting skipped because it does not have previous day sale? How to get the skipped row back again giving 0 sale for previous date?

[image]

Comment: Create a proper calendar table and use its dates, not the dates from the transactional  table

Comment: @RADO : This is a quick sample that I created. My actual calendar starts from 2005 to 2020 and has many more columns. My purpose is to understand the behavior of Power BI. Why it skips the rows for which data is not available and how to overcome this. I tried using IF(contains(Table,Table[sale] ,selectedvalue(table[sale]) = blank(),0,1). This is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new custom column in your table "Table" with below code. This new column will hold your expected results-

```
prev_day_sale = 

VAR yesterday = DATEADD('Table'[Date],-1,DAY)

VAR prev_day_sale = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Table'[Sale],
    'Table'[Date], yesterday
)

RETURN IF(
    prev_day_sale = BLANK(),
    0,
    prev_day_sale
)
```

Output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks..Your method works..Do you have any Idea why, my calculation is skipping rows..

Comment: it gives the expected result, but it's a bad practice to use a calculated column where a measure would be sufficient https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

Comment: Nice to see you have posted a better option (may be). But this is ridiculous to put a down vote on a solution that worked.... hahaha. Earning reputation is not a easy task FYI. @Stachu

Comment: Even if it works, it is a bad practice, an anti-pattern if you will. I downvoted it it because I believe it causes more issues than it solves

Answer (score 2):

You should use a measure for this, not a calculated column. Also SUMX is a definite overkill - you unnecessarily iterate over every row in `Table`

```
SumInRange = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sale]),DATEADD('Dim Date'[Value],-1,DAY))
```

[image]

Comment: Here is the output of your given measure - https://ibb.co/2N2n72Q can you please check if you are missing something as your sample image showing everything as expected.

Comment: you use Table[Date] in the visual not 'Dim Date'[Value], that's what is causeing the issue

Comment: Ok, I tried that as well and here is the output - https://ibb.co/4d6g9KT

Comment: Do you have the 1:many single direction relationship set up between the tables as described in step3 of the OP post?

Comment: Just ignore. I found the issue in my part. And obviously your solution is the better one. 1 plus vote from me and I wish OP notice this and accept your answer instead of mine.

Comment: I agree Stachu option is the best, but it's not giving the required output. @mkRabbani solution worked for me, So I'll keep his answer as accepted one. But thankyou all for your time and efforts

Comment: Hi @sam, i am getting your expected output here with Stachu's solution. try with a fresh table and adding columns - Date, Sale & SumInRange only. In my case I got the correct result this way. If you can use this solution in your report, obviously this the the better one :)

Comment: @sam what result do you get? do you have the correct field (from dimension) in the visual? Also it's a syntax for measure, not calculated column - you need to add it from scratch, rather than replacing your old calculated column syntax

Comment: @Stachu: I created a measure with your DAX formula. But the entire column is coming blank. I deleted the table and create a fresh table and kept only Table[date],Table[sale] and your measure. The image of output is : https://ibb.co/rmrn9tP

Comment: @sam in the visual use use `'Dim Date'[Value]` instead of `Table[Date]`. If you need the displayed Label to be `Date` you can change the `Dim Date` to `Dim Date = SELECTCOLUMNS( GENERATESERIES(DATE(2019,01,01),DATE(2019,12,31),1),"Date",[Value])` but with that you will have to recreate the relationship and adjust the syntax to match new naming

Comment: @Stachu: Now I am getting values after using dimension date table. But values are now coming same as sale column.See the image for details. https://ibb.co/g6QbPfR

Comment: @Stachu : I forgot to mention that I renamed the 'Dim Date'[Value] column to 'Dim Date'[Date]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this without changing your existing formula is by enabling the option **"Show items with no data"** for the Date attribute in visualization pane. Please see the screen shot for reference.

[image]